# How can i tell the server the public key from the crypthography module?

Tags: python, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to create a simple messenger in python with encryption using the cryptography module. I already got the client and server coded, but now im stuck on the part, where i tell the server my public key so the server can encrypt the group key or somekind of key which the client can decrypt with his private key. I tried sending the key using the regular kind of sending a string, but i'm just sending the memory address over. I also tried saving the key to a file and sending the file over, but thats not working either. How do i approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the key over a binary file , the client should transform this binary file into utf8 or whatever form that you want to use , here is the scenario for sending encrypted data to the client :

```
- server asks the client for the public key
- client sends public key with a binary file to the server
- server unpacks the binary file and transform it into another form
- server use public key extracted to encrypt data
- server sends encrypted data to the client
- client decrypt the encrypted data
```

You can do the same on the other side